# Wrote to one disk of raid array, files truncated, trying to recover data, arch linux

Tags: linux, raid, data-recovery, arch-linux

I'm trying to recover some data from a corrupt RAID1 pair and wanted some advice before I make matters worse.

This is how I caused the problem: I wanted to save some data prior to reinstalling my OS. I found an old computer with two magnetic disks in, both of which I inserted into the main computer and typed lsblk, which said something like, IIRC:

```
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0  59.6G  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0   1.8T  0 part 
  └─md127     ???    ?   1.8T  ? ????
sdb           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:1    0  59.6G  0 part 
└─sdb2        8:2    0   1.8T  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 896.8G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  34.4G  0 part [SWAP]
```

where the nvm is the main disk. I can't remember with certainty which of the two disks had the md127 on, but I think it was sda. mdadm was not installed at this time. (At least, not to my knowledge - it was a Manjaro box.) I found I could mount md127 and saved my precious data to it in a few tarballs. Then I wiped the main disk and reinstalled. At some point I installed mdadm in the new OS and mounted the RAID1 pair. I then found that the tarballs I'd saved were truncated.

How should I proceed to recover the rest of the tarballs?

I wonder if a simple fsck would do the trick, but I'm nervous to bang around at random.

ddrescue wouldn't be much help cos I don't have another 2TB disk in the house, and I'm not sure which, if either, of the magnetic disks still have useful data on.

Comment: Can you not just restore from last backup?

Comment: Off Topic:Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. Backups are standard practice since - hm - 60 years. Playing around with hard discs in non supported fashions is not. The data is gone - use a your backup.

Comment: Also is this a home-use question?

Comment: What backup? Yes it's home use. Sorry I didn't realise Server Fault excluded that.

Comment: If only it weren't literally the first words of our help and intro pages :) Don't worry, you're not the first and won't be the last